# Pandas merge and keep only non-matching records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

How can  I merge/join these two dataframes ONLY on "id". Produce 3 new dataframes:

- 1)R1 = Merged records
- 2)R2 = (DF1 - Merged records)
- 3)R3 = (DF2 - Merged records)

Using **pandas** in Python.

First dataframe (DF1)

```
|        id | name  |
|-----------|-------|
| 1         | Mark  |
| 2         | Dart  |
| 3         | Julia |
| 4         | Oolia |
| 5         | Talia |
```

Second dataframe (DF2)

```
|        id | salary |
|-----------|--------|
| 1         | 20     |
| 2         | 30     |
| 3         | 40     |
| 4         | 50     |
| 6         | 33     |
| 7         | 23     |
| 8         | 24     |
| 9         | 28     |
```

My solution for

```
R1 =pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='id', how='inner')
```

I am unsure that is the easiest way to get R2 and R3

R2 should look like

```
|        id | name  |
|-----------|-------|
| 5         | Talia |
```

R3 should look like:

```
|        id | salary |
|-----------|--------|
| 6         | 33     |
| 7         | 23     |
| 8         | 24     |
| 9         | 28     |
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn on `indicator` in `merge` and look for the corresponding values:

```
total_merge = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='outer', indicator=True)

R1 = total_merge[total_merge['_merge']=='both']
R2 = total_merge[total_merge['_merge']=='left_only']
R3 = total_merge[total_merge['_merge']=='right_only']
```

---

**Update**: Ben's suggestion would be something like this:

```
dfs = {k:v for k,v in total_merge.groupby('_merge')}
```

and then you can do, for examples:

```
dfs['both']
```

Comment: May be we can just do groupby ~ and output into dict ~

Comment: @YOBEN_S yes, that's indeed a very clean approach. This is just to match OP's expectation, which is somewhat inferior to your suggestion.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. But will be interested to know whatr @YOBEN_S solution looks like

Comment: @misguided see updated answer.